# Time Complexity to check if a number is an armsgstrong number or not

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time-complexity

I was having a discussion on the runtime cost of the algorithm to check if an number is an armstrong number or not with a friend. Just for those who don't know what an Armstrong number is:

> A number   is an Armstrong Number or narcissistic number if it is equal to the sum of its own digits raised to the power of the number of digits.

Here's the routine I wrote to check if the number is an Armstrong number or not:

```
bool check_armstrong_number(int num){

   int number_copy = num; // Store the number in another variable to compare afterwards
   int digits = 0; // Stores the number of digits in the number.

   // Calculate the number of digits in the number
   while(number_copy){
    number_copy = number_copy/10;
    digits++;
   }

   number_copy = num;

   int sum = 0;  // To construct numbers from sum of digits raise to the power number_of_digits.
   while(num){
       int unit_digit = num % 10; // Get the unit digit with the help of modulus operator.
       sum  = sum + std::pow(unit_digit,digits);  // Calculate unit_digit^digits
       num = num / 10;
    }
    return (sum == number_copy); // Returns true only if sum equals original number
  }
```

My friend says the algorithm is ***O(log N)*** , while I believe it is ***O(log^2(N))***. I think iteration over the digits is ***O(log N)*** operation(as the number of digits in an integer is of the order log N), and the std::pow(unit_digit,digits) is also around ***O(log N)*** for each calculation. So, ***O(log N)*** computation time for log N computation should be around ***O(log^2 N)***. Can anyone clarify this a bit?

Comment: If `digits` is O(log n) then `pow(unit, digits)` should be faster; the square-and-multiply algorithm is O(log b) where b is the power raised, so that's O(log log n). But this is assuming that multiplication of arbitrarily large numbers can be done in constant time, which is not a sensible assumption. I think neither of your answers is correct.

Comment: If iterating over the digits is O(log N), then with including power() in each iteration, how the complete operation is O(log(log N))? If I am not wrong, O(log(logN)) is faster than O(log N)? Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Given that there are only 88 such numbers, my guess is that you can do it in constant time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's O(log(n)*log(log(n)) .
Log(n) for iteration .
In pow(a,b) the complexity is log(b) . So here your b = log(n) .
So log(log(n)) for pow function .